# How to display list from DB in android with links?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, onclick

I'm new to android and I'm trying to make a simple android program that will display rows of data from sqlite table.

I'd like to make a list wherein each row is clickable and once clicked, will trigger probably an onclick function based on which row it was clicked from(like passing parameter of the row clicked).

Can anyone tell me how to do this? or provide links to sample applications about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are 2 things that you are asking for. 1. Populate your list from the database 2. execute the code or launch something when a row is clicked. Can you be specific what exactly is your problem. Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: Ken, check the documentation for [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) and read a tutorial or book (Hello Android is quite good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot of example for this. As as starting go through the android website - developer.android.com. It contains tutorials for database and lists and any other thing you want. Go in resource section to view the sample codes. Try exploring...

Comment: Sorry, actually I was able to make a list from a table, all the rows were displayed using a single textview in main.xml, the problem is that I want each row to have different parameters when clicked so that it will be checked and produce different result.

Comment: instead of using textview use listview to display the items. This will allow you to write a code on selection of each row or item. There you can perform something like onListItemClick(). You can write your code by overriding this method.